# Error when trying to run my React Native app on Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I've built my React Native app and tested and troubleshooted with my iOS devices for months. Now I'm trying to built and test the app on Android for the first time. The thing is, that I keep getting errors trying to run the Android-version of my app. After hours of debugging and troubleshooting, I tried to create a new RN project and see if that could run on my emulator and device. I got that part working and then I wanted to copy/paste the files of my existing app project into the new project.

I pasted my existing assets, styles, the source JS-files and the package.json file into the new project, ran `npm install` and then I ended up with the exact same error message as I had in the original project when I run `react-native run-android`.

The full error message is here:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/yoga/proguard-annotations/1.14.1/proguard-annotations-1.14.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/yoga/proguard-annotations/1.14.1/proguard-annotations-1.14.1.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/.m2/repository/com/facebook/yoga/proguard-annotations/1.14.1/proguard-annotations-1.14.1.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/yoga/proguard-annotations/1.14.1/proguard-annotations-1.14.1.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/yoga/proguard-annotations/1.14.1/proguard-annotations-1.14.1.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/yoga/proguard-annotations/1.14.1/proguard-annotations-1.14.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2
   > Could not find com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fbjni/fbjni-java-only/0.0.3/fbjni-java-only-0.0.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/fbjni/fbjni-java-only/0.0.3/fbjni-java-only-0.0.3.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/.m2/repository/com/facebook/fbjni/fbjni-java-only/0.0.3/fbjni-java-only-0.0.3.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/fbjni/fbjni-java-only/0.0.3/fbjni-java-only-0.0.3.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/fbjni/fbjni-java-only/0.0.3/fbjni-java-only-0.0.3.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/fbjni/fbjni-java-only/0.0.3/fbjni-java-only-0.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2
   > Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/.m2/repository/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - file:/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-video

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

    at makeError (/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/MyUser/MyAppFolder/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

I've tried to run `./gradlew clean` in the android-folder without any luck. My build.gradle-file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
    }
    repositories {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()

           // jcenter()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you know what to do or if you have experienced a similar issue!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I've hit this same issue and have temporarily resolved it by uninstalling react-native-video (npm uninstall --save react-native-video).  That's not a great answer as I need that component, but I don't have a full solution yet. I think somehow com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4. is required by react-native-video but has gotten lost or removed.  Other thoughts are welcome.

UPDATE: Resolved! In your build.gradle in your Android folder you need to add the repository "jcenter()" in allprojects (not in build dependencies) like this...

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You are right about the react-native-video, but like you I need that component too... I suspect that there is a misfit between different versions of RN, Gradle and JDK.

Comment: Resolved!  Edited above as well.  In your build.gradle in your Android folder you need to add the repository "jcenter()" in allprojects (not in build dependecies) like this...


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }

Comment: What a ludicrous status quo to be presented with upon first run of `react-native init`! Now I have warnings all throughout my gradle files and terminal logs every time I build, because jcenter was deprecated **ages** ago and will be removed completly soon! Anyway thanks for the answer to this strange and frustrating issue. +1

Comment: @Kenny83 I couldn't agree more. React native has been a terrible experience to work with. This is one of many things that just don't work "out of the box" or have documentation that matches the real world. Everything seems like it's years out of date and nobody seems to care if they release things that work.

Comment: @SpliFF Yep you hit the nail right on the head! Especially what you said about package developers not caring whether their packages actually work or not. It's infuriating isn't it?!

Comment: jcenter() no longer works

Comment: This is now broken. As of today jcentre went down and the build fails if you try to include it. Need another solution now...

Answer (score 17):

It's best to only pull specific packages from jcenter() in android/build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .... # Keep the rest
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in app build.gradle i have to add this or in the package as in the package i am not able to find it

Comment: "Jcenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere" showing in IDE. And its no longer support. Can replace with mavenCentral()

Answer (score 4):

The solutions on this page are now broken, because as of today jcenter finally went down. Newer alpha versions of react-native-video-processing have the fix in them, but if like me, you just want to get it building for now then apply [this patch](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/commit/fd821d2c5cb9d2bc8d52396250993f965886b567) in `node_modules/react-native-video-processing/android/build.gradle`:

Instead of:

```
implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
```

use:

```
implementation 'com.github.thang2162:Android-ScalableVideoView:v1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because jCenter is removed from latest react native and com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview is only published there you need to add jCenter again as a repository but I would advice to define the package so other dependencies are not fetched/taken from jCenter anymore. Because jCenter does not allow any updates anymore of any package all other packages should be taken from mavenCentral for example.

You can add jcenter to android/build.gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .... # Keep the rest
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Jcenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates: newer library versions may be available elsewhere" showing in IDE. And its no longer support. Can replace with mavenCentral()