# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses '

Tags: java, android-studio

### Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> - https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.4.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.10.2 > com.facebook.react:react-native-video:5.1.1-jitsi-8711917

Please help me!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68841906/608312) probably fixes it. If not, there's a [few other suggestions on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2454).